# AsyncTask: Can't update UI from publishProgress. Error: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Developer.Android says PublishProgress resides in UI Thread and thus I should be able to alter the UI from Publish Progress.

However, I get this error:

android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

On This Code:

Calling Activity

```
public class AttendanceOperations extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView remaningTimeTV;
databaseTimeTableClass aDB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_attendance_operations);



    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);

    remaningTimeTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.remaningTime);
    aDB = new databaseTimeTableClass(this);

    String currentClass = aDB.attendanceSubjectView(hours, minute);

    TextView newClass = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nextclass);
    newClass.setText(currentClass);

    new timerForUpComing(remaningTimeTV).execute();

}}
```

Async Class

```
public class timerForUpComing extends AsyncTask <Void, Integer, Void>{

public boolean a = true;
public int differenceMinute;
public int currentMinute;

TextView timeView;

public timerForUpComing(TextView timeRem)
{
    this.timeView=timeRem;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {



    while (a)
    {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        currentMinute = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        differenceMinute = 60 - currentMinute;
        Log.d("d ", String.valueOf(differenceMinute));
        publishProgress(differenceMinute);
        try {
           Thread.sleep(999);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(differenceMinute==1)
            a = false;
    }

   return null;
}


public void publishProgress(int remaining)
{
    timeView.setText(String.valueOf(remaining));

} }
```

I am passing TextView fromm class AttendanceOperations to timeForUpComing via Constructor, so I can update it from PublishProgress.

And this doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Android says PublishProgress resides in UI Thread and thus I should be able to alter the UI from Publish Progress.

`AsyncTask` has its own `publishProgress()` method. You do not *implement* `publishProgress()`. You *call* `publishProgress()`. You *implement* `onProgressUpdate()`, and in `onProgressUpdate()`, you can update your UI.

This is covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

So, change:

```
public void publishProgress(int remaining)
{
    timeView.setText(String.valueOf(remaining));

}
```

to:

```
@Override
public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... remaining) {
    timeView.setText(remaining.toString());
}
```

Also, [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Threads/AsyncTask) demonstrates the use of `AsyncTask`, including calling `publishProgress()` and implementing `onProgressUpdate()`.